# How to parse API data in XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm currently working on an application through WPF and wonder what's the better option in my case. I have a web based API that originally prints it's own XML and fills in the elements with it's data, but since this'll eventually be on a live server I thought it might seem a bit more convenient if the executable creates an XML file and parses API data into it.

If my option seems better, how do I write designated data to XML elements? I'm sorry if my question is a bit vague.

My JSON classes

```
[DataContract]
public class ShipmentDetails
{
    [DataMember(Name="salutationCode")]
    public string salutationCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="firstName")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="surName")]
    public string surName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="streetName")]
    public string streetName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="houseNumber")]
    public string houseNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="zipCode")]
    public string zipCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="city")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="countryCode")]
    public string countryCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="email")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="language")]
    public string language { get; set; }
}
```

```
[DataContract]
public class BillingDetails
{
    [DataMember(Name="salutationCode")]
    public string salutationCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="firstName")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="surName")]
    public string surName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="streetName")]
    public string streetName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="houseNumber")]
    public string houseNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="zipCode")]
    public string zipCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="city")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="countryCode")]
    public string countryCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="email")]
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomerDetails
{
    [DataMember(Name="shipmentDetails")]
    public ShipmentDetails shipmentDetails { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="billingDetails")]
    public BillingDetails billingDetails { get; set; }
}
```

```
[DataContract]
public class OrderItem
{
    [DataMember(Name="orderItemId")]
    public string orderItemId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="offerReference")]
    public string offerReference { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="ean")]
    public string ean { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="quantity")]
    public int quantity { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="offerPrice")]
    public double offerPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="offerId")]
    public string offerId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="transactionFee")]
    public double transactionFee { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="latestDeliveryDate")]
    public string latestDeliveryDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="expiryDate")]
    public string expiryDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="offerCondition")]
    public string offerCondition { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="cancelRequest")]
    public bool cancelRequest { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="fulfilmentMethod")]
    public string fulfilmentMethod { get; set; }
}
```

```
[DataContract]
public class Example
{
    [DataMember(Name="orderId")]
    public string orderId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="pickUpPoint")]
    public bool pickUpPoint { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="dateTimeOrderPlaced")]
    public DateTime dateTimeOrderPlaced { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="customerDetails")]
    public CustomerDetails customerDetails { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="orderItems")]
    public IList<OrderItem> orderItems { get; set; }
}
```

My XML

```cs
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("Orders.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("start");
    writer.WriteElementString("customer_id", "935933");
    writer.WriteStartElement("orders");
    writer.WriteStartElement("order");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_id", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_ref", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_dropshipment", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_dlv_adr_name", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_dlv_adr_street", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_dlv_adr_housenr", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_dlv_adr_zipcode", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_dlv_adr_city", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_dlv_adr_email", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_dlv_adr_phone", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("order_dlv_adr_country_isocode", "");
    writer.WriteStartElement("orderrows");
    writer.WriteStartElement("orderrow");
    writer.WriteElementString("orderrow_sku", "");
    writer.WriteElementString("orderrow_qty", "");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.Flush();
}
```

XML mapping in PHP

```php
$order->addChild('order_id',$info['orderId']);
$order->addChild('order_ref',$info['orderId']);// order_ref is usually the same as the order_id
$order->addChild('order_dropshipment',"Y"); // Yes and No if there's no dropshipment needed
$order->addChild('order_dlv_adr_name',$info['customerDetails']['shipmentDetails']['firstName'].' '.$info['customerDetails']['shipmentDetails']['surName']);
$order->addChild('order_dlv_adr_street',$info['customerDetails']['shipmentDetails']['streetName']);
$order->addChild('order_dlv_adr_housenr',$info['customerDetails']['shipmentDetails']['houseNumber']);
$order->addChild('order_dlv_adr_zipcode',$info['customerDetails']['shipmentDetails']['zipCode']);
$order->addChild('order_dlv_adr_city',$info['customerDetails']['shipmentDetails']['city']);
$order->addChild('order_dlv_adr_email',COMPANY_EMAIL);
$order->addChild('order_dlv_adr_phone',COMPANY_PHONE);
$order->addChild('order_dlv_adr_country_isocode',$info['customerDetails']['shipmentDetails']['countryCode']);
```

Desired output

```xml
<start>
   <customer_id>935933</customer_id>
   <orders>
      <order>
         <order_id>11864523</order_id>
         <order_ref>11864523</order_ref>
         <order_dropshipment>Y</order_dropshipment>
         <order_dlv_adr_name>Fred Bellens</order_dlv_adr_name>
         <order_dlv_adr_street>Elisabetaelaan</order_dlv_adr_street>
         <order_dlv_adr_housenr>2</order_dlv_adr_housenr>
         <order_dlv_adr_zipcode>3200</order_dlv_adr_zipcode>
         <order_dlv_adr_city>Aarschot</order_dlv_adr_city>
         <order_dlv_adr_email>*our mail*</order_dlv_adr_email>
         <order_dlv_adr_phone>077 396 814</order_dlv_adr_phone>
         <order_dlv_adr_country_isocode>BE</order_dlv_adr_country_isocode>
         <orderrows>
            <orderrow>
               <orderrow_sku>KA0 14315 21_122</orderrow_sku>
               <orderrow_qty>1</orderrow_qty>
            </orderrow>
         </orderrows>
      </order>
   </orders>
</start>
```

Comment: Please share with us the desired XML output as well.

Comment: Of course, I'll edit it in

Comment: Could also provide a mapping between the xml and your data model. Because for instance there is no such property which holds the `customer_id`.

Comment: Customer ID is consistent, that is just hardcoded into it so there's no need to link it

Comment: it was just an example. There are a couple of xml nodes which is not obvious (based on naming) how should be retrieved from the data model, like: `order_ref`, `order_dropshipment`, etc. So, please provide us the mapping unless we can't help you.

Comment: This is all the mapping I can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways how you can achieve that desired XML.
Let me show you two different ways:

#### XElement

Instead of relying on the `XmlWriter` [we can construct the desired structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/create-xml-trees) with `XElement`.
In your case the initialization of the tree could look similar to this:

```cs
var order = //...;
var shipment = order.customerDetails.billingDetails;
var xml = new XElement("start",
    new XElement("customer_id", 935933),
    new XElement("orders",
        new XElement("order",
            new XElement("order_id", order.orderId),
            new XElement("order_ref", order.orderId),
            new XElement("order_dropshipment", "Y"),
            new XElement("order_dlv_adr_name", $"{shipment.firstName} {shipment.surName}"),
            new XElement("order_dlv_adr_street", shipment.streetName),
            new XElement("order_dlv_adr_housenr", shipment.houseNumber),
            new XElement("order_dlv_adr_zipcode", shipment.zipCode),
            new XElement("order_dlv_adr_city", shipment.city),
            new XElement("order_dlv_adr_email", "TBD"),
            new XElement("order_dlv_adr_phone", "TBD"),
            new XElement("order_dlv_adr_country_isocode", shipment.countryCode)
        )));
```

Then the persistence logic would look like this:

```cs
using var sampleXml = new FileStream("sample.xml", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
using var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(sampleXml);
fileWriter.Write(xml.ToString());
fileWriter.Flush();
```

And that's it.

#### JsonConvert

As an alternative if you already have the desired structure in json then you can easily convert it to XML via `JsonConvert`'s [DeserializeXmlNode](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeXmlNode_1.htm):

```cs
var orderInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data); 
XmlDocument orderInXml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(orderInJson);
```

And here is the persistence logic:

```cs
using var sampleXml = new XmlTextWriter("sample2.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
using var fileWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sampleXml);
orderInXml.WriteTo(fileWriter);
fileWriter.Flush();
```

Comment: I assume I have to complete with the empty namespace that holds all the classes? I'm sorry, I'm still learning - because I have a separate data class that retrieves the API data with a httpclient/reponsemessage

Comment: @Talon Sorry but I don't get it. Which of the above two approaches are we talking about?

Comment: I'm sorry, the first one "var order = //...;"

Comment: @Talon I thought that your provided data classes (like `ShipmentDetails`, `OrderItem`, etc.) are the ones that you are using here as well.  That's why I used navigation properties like: `customerDetails.billingDetails`.

Comment: I do have data classes, but they're in a different namespace, hence why I asked - just to be sure

Comment: @Talon C# code's namespace should not be a problem. If you need to use XML namespaces in your generated XML that's another story :D